# Php, ReflectionClass, getConstructor() bumpts into a trait's constructor, how to dodge it?

Tags: php, reflection

so far I have this:

```
class A
{
    public function __construct($v1,$v2) {}
}

class B extends A
{
}

class C extends B
{
}

echo (new \ReflectionClass('C'))->getConstructor()->class;
```

this works like a charm, it produces `A` as expected. So far so good.
But then a `trait` came into my way:

```
trait X
{
    public function __construct($fake) {}
}

class A
{
    public function __construct($v1,$v2) {}
}

class B extends A
{
    use X;
}

class C extends B
{
}

echo (new \ReflectionClass('C'))->getConstructor()->class;
```

it now produces `B` ! But I want to know the parameters of `A::constructor`, not `X::constructor`! How to dodge it?

Comment: If an intermediate class overrides the constructor, then C's constructor is that intermediate constructor. If you tried to instantiate `C` you'd need to supply arguments fitting `X::__construct`, not `A::__construct`. If you arbitrarily want `A::__construct` you need to traverse the parent chain up to `A`; but that's not C's constructor.

Comment: Probably showing you that you shouldn't have a constructor on a trait.